# How do write this in do notation?

Tags: haskell

I'm working through "Write yourself a scheme interpreter in 48 hours" and one exercise is to write a function using do notation. This is the function:

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = liftM (Number . read) $ many1 digit
```

I tried the following, but that didn't work:

```
parseNumber2 :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber2 = do digits <- many1 digit
                  return $ liftM $  (Number . read) digits
```

Never mind. I indented the code incorrectly

Comment: The type of `liftM` is `(Monad m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`. In this case, `liftM` is `fmap` in the `Parser` monad. But `(Number . read) digits` is not a monadic value, so you are encountering a type error (reason one: `(Number . read) digits` is not a function, but is being used as a function; reason two: `(Number . read) digits` is not a monadic value, so it doesn't have type `m a` for some monad `m`). However, `return (Number (read (digits)))` used without `liftM` is a monadic value, and equivalent (when placed on the last line) to the original definition.

Answer (score 6):

Once you've unpacked `digits`, you don't need the `liftM` anymore. So it's just:

```
return $ Number $ read digits
```

Answer (score 4):

I hopped on the #haskell IRC channel and asked lambdabot:

```
11:25 < dmwit> ?src liftM
11:25 < lambdabot> liftM f m1 = do { x1 <- m1; return (f x1) }
11:27 < dmwit> ?src ($)
11:27 < lambdabot> f $ x = f x
```

(If you don't want to ask lambdabot, you can also ask [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?q=liftM) and click the source link in the documentation.)

So, let's fill in `f` and `m1`:

```
liftM (Number . read) $ many1 digit
    ={definition of ($)}
liftM (Number . read) (many1 digit)
    ={definition of liftM}
do { x1 <- (many1 digit); return ((Number . read) x1) }
    ={expand to layout form, eliminate redundant parentheses}
do
    x1 <- many1 digit
    return ((Number . read) x1)
```

You can write half a dozen variations of this of varying syntactic aesthetic, but here's my favorite, after expanding the definitions of `(.)` and `($)` a few times:

```
    ={definitions of (.) and ($)}
do
    x1 <- many1 digit
    return . Number . read $ x1
```